# Parsing XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have been having issues with parsing some XML. I have no control over the structure of the XML I receive.

```
<response>
  <variable name = "variable_name">variable value</variable>
  <variable name = "variable_name">variable value</variable>
</response>
```

I need to get the variable_name and value and write them to the webpage. However the number of of variables is dynamic.

I have already created functions for parsing different xml responses but the structure I receive is different for these.

How can I adapt the following code for the response?

```
function parseSystem(xml){
     ControllerFound = true;
      $(xml).find("response").each(function()
       {
            $("#ProjectName").append($(this).find("projectName").text());
});
```

Cheers

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
function parseSystem(xml){
      $('variable', xml).each(function()
       {
            var var_instance = $(this);
            $("#container").append("Name: "+var_instance.attr('name')+"Value: "+ var_instance.text());
       }
}
```

and having on the html a `container` to append the values:

```
 <div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You would need to make the selector $('variable', xml), and you should probably prevent using $(this) twice by writing it to a variable.

Comment: Will this actually write both responses to the webpage though. It looks to me (I'm new to Javascript / jquery) that it would write the values to #ProjectName twice, which is not the desired functionality.

Comment: @Michael I think now the response is a bit more clear, you need a _container_ on the web page where you can add the values.